# API Usage limits

Tags: rest-api, limits

I was trying to find limits of Rest API calls an org can made in a day.

This article '[API Usage Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm)'  helped me until a particular line confused me which says

> Any action that sends a call to the API counts toward usage limits, except the following:
>
> 1.Outbound messages 2. Apex callouts

I'm making a Rest API call (to same org although)  which I think, could be referred as 'Apex Callout' also.
Would it counted for API limit(max 1M for enterprise edition as per article) or not or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3):

Every inbound call into the API counts against your 24 hour limit - note: the limit is per 24 hours, not per day - the difference is that if you make 10,000 API calls at 10:01 GMT today, those calls are removed from your count at 10:01 GMT the next day, not at 00:00 GMT. A small, but important thing to remember.

So, if you made a call out back into your own org (I am not sure if that would really be the best way of doing this as I would rather have one class that handles the data coming in via a REST call that then hands the processing off to a common function so that other process (such as where you are doing the callout) handles the real work, so you avoid the expense (time/resources) of a REST call), the incoming REST call would count againt your 24 hour REST limitation.

Comment: I think the phrase you're looking for is "rolling 24 hours"; meaning that it finds the peak number of transactions over a 24 hour period where the start time will vary to capture the 24 hour segment during which the peak occurred.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be counted as API call to org. To check your API usage limits, please go to System overview:

https://emea.salesforce.com/setup/systemOverview.apexp?setupid=SystemOverview

Also you can check for API calls made by different users in last 7 days with following report, this might help you figure out exactly what is the API consumption from your Rest API call.

https://emea.salesforce.com/00O?rt=104